# HTTPS request fails in Docker >= 1.10 with virtualized network

Tags: https, docker

I experience a problem that a HTTPS connections cannot be established from inside a Docker container with version 1.10.3 or 1.11.2.

I tried with apt-get, curl and wget and all fail as soon as a HTTPS connection should be established.

E.g., the following command fails:

```
$ docker run -it ubuntu-curl curl -v https://www.google.com
[...]
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
* Closing connection 0
```

The Docker image `ubuntu-curl` is based on `ubuntu:latest`, the only change was `apt-get update ; apt-get install curl`.

If I use HTTP instead of HTTPs, it works. If I issue the same command from the host, it works. If I start the container **without network virtualization** (docker run `--net="host"`), it works. If I downgrade Docker (I tried 1.6.2 and 1.9.1), it works as well.

Any hints what could be wrong? I tried with two hosts, Ubuntu 14 LTS and CoreOS stable without relevant customization - both run inside a OpenStack cluster.

Iptables of the host (although I would not understand why iptables should only block HTTPs traffic):

```
$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:12345

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: FYI it appears to be a bug in OpenStack, I filed a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/1595762 - also seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300497/docker-container-not-connecting-to-https-endpoints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was given a solution by the [Docker community](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20178#issuecomment-228531711)

OpenStack network seems to use lower MTU values and Docker does not infer the MTU settings from the host's network card [since 1.10](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22028).

To run docker daemon with custom MTU settings, you can follow [this blog post](https://rahulait.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/modifying-default-mtu-for-docker-containers/), that says:

```
$ cp /lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Edit a line in the new file to look like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// –mtu=1454
```

MTU of 1454 is the value that seems to be common with OpenStack. You can look it up in your host using ifconfig.

Finally restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service docker restart
```